# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf + PostgreSQL не добавляются записи в БД через select option

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf, html-select

Делаю приложение на Spring Boot с PostgreSQL и Thymeleaf. В представлении сделал форму для добавления записи в БД, где несколько полей ввода предназначены для обычного текстового ввода, а еще два - с выпадающим списком `select option`. Так вот при добавлении записи в БД поля с обычным текстовым вводом добавляются, а с выпадающим списком - нет, там просто пустое место.
В БД одно из этих двух полей с выпадающим списком (`gender`) имеет тип `Enum`, а другое (`breed`) - `varchar(30)` (и оба не добавляются). Никаких ошибок не выводится. Может непонятно объяснил, но по-другому не выходит.

Сама таблица имеет такую структуру:

```
create type gender as enum ('MALE', 'FEMALE');
create table dogs (id int not null generated by default as identity primary key, nickname varchar(20) not null, name varchar(40), breed varchar(30), date_of_birth timestamp without time zone, puppies_count int, gender gender);
```

Консоль:

```
2023-08-09T18:45:53.968+03:00 DEBUG 17908 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into dogs (breed,date_of_birth,gender,name,nickname,puppies_count) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into dogs (breed,date_of_birth,gender,name,nickname,puppies_count) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Представление:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Собаки</title>
 <style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${isUserAuth}">Выйти</div>
<div th:unless="${isUserAuth}">Войти</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>user@ukr.net</p> <a href="/logout">Logout</a>  
</div>

<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Hello, guest! Please <a href="/login">Login</a> or <a href="/signup">SignUp</a></p> 
</div>
<table border="1" color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Кличка</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Пол</b></td>
        <td><b>Порода</b></td>
        <td><b>Дата рождения</b></td>
        <td><b>Щенки</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}" id="dog.nickname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}" id="dog.name"/></td>
            <td><select th.field="*{dog.gender}" id="dog.gender">
                    <option th:each="genderSex : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderSex.sex}" th:text="${genderSex.sex}"></option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select  th.field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">
                    <option th:each="breed : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breed.type}" th:text="${breed.type}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}" id="dog.dateOfBirth"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.puppies}" id="dog.puppies"/></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
<tr  th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
       <td th:text="${dog.id}">1</td>
       <td th:text="${dog.nickname}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.name}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.gender}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.breed}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.dateOfBirth}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.puppies}"></td>
        <br>
 </tr>
 </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Сущность:

```
package com.example.demo6.entities;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
public class Dog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Nickname should not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "Nickname should be between 3 and 30 characters long")
    private String nickname;
    //@Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "Name should be between 3 and 30 characters long")
    private String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "Gender")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    
    private Gender gender;
    //@Column(columnDefinition = "Breed")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Breed breed;
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name = "puppies_count")
    private int puppies;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Breed getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(Breed breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDateTime dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public int getPuppies() {
        return puppies;
    }

    public void setPuppies(int puppies) {
        this.puppies = puppies;
    }

    public Dog() {}
    
    public enum Breed {
        WHWT("Вест Хайленд Вайт Терьер"), 
        SCOTTISH_T("Скотч Терьер"), 
        SEALYHAM_T("Силихем Терьер"), 
        JRT("Джек Рассел Терьер"), 
        AUSTRALIAN_S("Австралийская овчарка"), 
        METIS("Метис/Дворняга"),
        OTHER("Другая");
        
        String type;
        Breed(String type){this.type = type;}
        public String getType(){return type;}
    }
    
    public enum Gender {
        MALE("Мальчик"), 
        FEMALE("Девочка"); 
    
        String sex;
        Gender(String sex){this.sex = sex;}
        public String getSex(){return sex;}
    }
}
```

Comment: В случае с `genderSex` попробуйте сделать так: в `th:value` написать просто `genderSex`. А в случае с `breed` у вас ошибка в атрибуте Таймлифа: вы поставили точку вместо двоеточия.

Comment: С `genderSex` попробовал - не помогает. А с `breed` - не могли бы указать где именно перепутал, а то в упор не вижу :)

Comment: Вот тут: `<td><select  th.field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">`. А у вас с созданием `type` в Postgres когда-нибудь работала вставка из Таймлифа? Если это в первый раз делаете, то я бы попробовал заменить этот кастомный тип просто на строку в БД. Просто я так не делал, поэтому если оставлять такой тип, то подсказать не смогу.

Comment: Нет, первый раз делаю и не работает. Да не хочется отказываться от идеи использовать `enum`. Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: А замена точки помогла?

Comment: Попробуйте в обоих случаях в `th:value` написать просто итерируемую переменную, без обращения к полю через точку, так как Spring конвертирует `enum` из строкового имени, получаемого по `toString()`, непосредственно в объект-член `enum`-а. А в сущности у первого `enum`, как и у второго, попробуйте закомментировать `@Column`.

Comment: Извините, но я до сих пор не вижу где перепутал точку с двоеточием :) . Не могли бы написать как должно быть? Может быть я просто не знаю правильный синтаксис. Остальное сейчас попробую.

Comment: Было: `<td><select  th.field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">`, стало: `<td><select  th:field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">`.  После `select` идёт атрибут Таймлифа, и у вас там точка вместо двоеточия. А глобально это находится в том месте вашей страницы, где вы используете поле `breed` в форме.

Comment: Вот я идиот :) в упор не видел. Тем более она в обоих `select` стояла. Да, помогло изменение точки, спасибо. Теперь выдает какую-то ошибку, но там я думаю дальше сам разберусь.

Comment: Можете оформить как ответ? Я его отмечу тогда как принятый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего, у вас ошибка в синтаксисе Thymeleaf. В строках

```
<td><select th.field="*{dog.gender}" id="dog.gender">
```

и

```
<td><select  th.field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">
```

поставлена точка вместо двоеточия.

Помимо этого, если вы из Thymeleaf-формы заполняете поля, которые являются перечислениями (`enum`), то в качестве `th:value` не нужно писать свои кастомные псевдонимы для членов перечисления.

Потому что Spring автоматически по строковому представлению члена `enum`-а превращает его в непосредственно объект. А "Джек Рассел Терьера" превратить в "JRT" ему будет проблематично.

Поэтому в `th:value` можно передавать, например, просто итерируемый по перечислению объект, так как, к примеру, в таком случае

```
th:each="each : ${enum}"
```

для `each` вызовется `toString()`, который у перечисления возвращает `name`. И тогда Spring легко его конвертирует в тот член `enum`-а, который и подразумевается.